Why is it Trojan and not Troyan or Troian?
Wikipedia:

Troy (Ancient Greek: Τροία, romanized: Troíā; Latin: Trōia)

Wiktionary lists Troyan and Troian as obsolete or dated forms of Trojan.
How and why did the word come to be only Trojan in the English language? (Are there any other words that have undergone something similar and might there be some more general explanation?)
Ngram suggests that Troian and Troyan were about as common as Trojan around 1860 to 1890.


Ngram does go back beyond 1800—and the relevant graph shows a brief blip of popularity for the spelling "Troyan" in the first half of the 1600s, although there is an even earlier blip in favor of "Trojan" in the late 1500s.

For its part, Early English Books Online, which covers publications in English from 1475 to 1700, finds 1,244 publications that contain the spelling "Trojan," 441 with the spelling "Troyan," and 186 with the spelling "Troian." Some of the results are duplicates, but there are virtually no false positives in EEBO search results.

@SvenYargs: Thanks for that info about Ngram. Edited my Q accordingly

Compare Trajan/Marcus Ulpius Traianus.

The OED is rather vague, aside from showing Troyan/Troian to be much older - the earliest spelling as Trojan is from 1649. It says of the etymology "The spelling Troian apparently stood originally for Troyan; later it probably represents Trojan." I'm not quite sure what that means but maybe it reflects the ambiguity over "i" and "j" in middle and early modern English where they weren't distinct letters and might represent a vowel or a consonant, and someone got confused and started pronouncing it /dʒ/.

The spellings Troja and Trojanus (with the letter 'j') were also used in Latin, and Trojan is ultimately adopted from Latin. Here is the etymology of Trojan from Etymonline:

Middle English Troian, "of or pertaining to ancient Troy," from Old English Troian, from Latin Trojanus, from Troia, Troja "Troy," from the Greek name for the city, said to be from Tros, name of a king of Phrygia, the mythical founder of Troy.

Note: OED mentions the Latin etymon Trōja also.
In the OED, the spelling Trojan is first mentioned in a citation from the translation of the Latin poem Georgics by Latin poet Virgil, translated by a Scottish translator named John Ogilby in 1649:

Long since enough we with our Blood did pay What might the Trojan Perjury defray.

This work may have influenced the adoption of the spelling 'Trojan' in translations of the time, which subsequently shaped its broader usage in later periods.
As to why Latin had two spellings, here is a good explanation about the semiwovels 'v' and 'i' in Latin:

In Latin, even though semivowels are phonemes, or unique sounds, they have no special letters used for them. The letters V and I were used to write the sounds /w/ and /j/, and these same letters were also used to write the vowels /u/ and /i/ in the same order. For example, Gaius Julius Caesar was written as Gaivs Ivlivs Caesar and wine was written as vinvm. The letter J was added after the fall of the Roman Empire to write the semivowel /j/ to show the difference between /j/ and /i/. - Wikipedia

The Wikipedia article for the letter 'j' has this note also:

The first English language books to make a clear distinction in writing between ⟨i⟩ and ⟨j⟩ were the King James Bible 1st Revision Cambridge 1629 and an English grammar book published in 1633.

Here is another valuable source that discusses semivowels in Latin within the broader classification of sounds: https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/classification-sounds

And "Y" is just "Greek I"

Would John Ogilby have pronounced it Troyan or Trojan (same as present day)?

John Ogilby, translating Virgil's Georgics in 1649, would likely have pronounced "Trojan" similarly to how we do today, with the /dʒ/ sound for "j" (as in "judge"). By the mid-17th century (during the Early Modern English period), the phonetic distinction between "I" and "J" was already well-established. In Middle English, the letters i and j, and u and v, had not yet become phonetically distinct. For instance, a written 'u' might be pronounced as /v/, or a 'j' as /i/.

Just one point could be clarified about the Wikipedia entry to do with the Roman letters then written 'V'  and 'I'.  We call the first of these 'vee'.  The Roman 'V' is actually a letter 'u', as in 'bush'.  That is why we call "W" a 'double-u' and not a 'double-vee'.  The English Wednesday would be transliterated  to 'Vednesday' - as in 'ooednesday', a 'w' sound.  Neither Greek nor Roman had a letter 'J':  just the letter 'I'as in 'igloo'. So 'Troia' makes the 'i' sound like the letter 'y', which is why we have 'Troy'.
